# How to use hamlet template with route parameter?

Tags: forms, routes, yesod, hamlet

I'm working on a yesod app based on the `yesod-postgres` stack template. I have a route defined in `config/routes` that has the form:

```
foo/edit/#Text EditFooR GET
```

In my hamlet template, I want to write

```
<form method=post action=@{EditFooR}#forms enctype=#{formEnctype}>
                    ^{formWidget}

                    <button type="submit">
                        Submit
```

and in my Handler I'd like to write:

```
getEditFooR :: T.Text -> Handler Html
getEditFooR name = do
    ....
    text <- findTextByName name

    (formWidget, formEnctype) <- generateFormPost (editFooForm text)
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "editFoo")
```

Except that I need to provide the parameter to the `@{EditFooR}` route. How is this done in the Hamlet file/Handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the .hamlet template should have the format:

```
<form method=post action=@{EditFooR fooName}#forms enctype=#{formEnctype}>
                ^{formWidget}

                <button type="submit">
                    Submit
```

and the `Handler` should have the format:

```
getEditFooR :: T.Text -> Handler Html
getEditFooR name = do
    ....
    text <- findTextByName name
    fooName <- "something or other"

   (formWidget, formEnctype) <- generateFormPost (editFooForm text)
       defaultLayout $ do
       $(widgetFile "editFoo")
```